# Encrypted SD card corrupted

Tags: mount, truecrypt

I can't mount a encrypted SD card with Truecrypt anymore.

> ```
> mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/truecrypt1,
>        missing codepage or helper program, or other error
>        In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
>        dmesg | tail  or so
> ```

Usually if this happens to a normal partition, runing `fsck` on it will solve my problems. But what do I do with a encrypted partition?

Comment: This looks so much like when I try to mount my USB (not encrypted). What do you get from dmesg?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create the `/dev/mapper/truecrypt1` device without trying to mount the contained file system, do this (replace `/dev/sda1` by the SD card device):

```
sudo truecrypt --filesystem=none --slot=1 /dev/sda1
```

To confirm that there is still readable data to be found, you could first do something like this to look for text content (hit ctrl+c to stop):

```
sudo cat /dev/mapper/truecrypt1 | strings
```

Assuming the `/dev/mapper/truecrypt1` block device has been successfully created, you can run normal tools like `fsck` on that device.

Comment: `/dev/mapper/truecrypt1` is not there when the error pops up. I assume it is removed again...

Comment: @Stefan: I've added instructions to create that device now.

Comment: perfect answer. +1